# Android Swipe View, Delete a page

Tags: android, swipe, deletion, delete, page

I have an Android application with a swipe view. The user is able to add pages with a floating action button. But I cannot figure where to put the "delete this page" action.

I have a floating action button that, when pressed reveal two floating action button to add a *row* and add a *page*.
My first idea was to add another button to delete the current page but that goes over the guidelines.

> Make floating action buttons positive actions like Create, Favorite, Share, Navigate, and Explore.
>
> -- http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html#buttons-floating-action-button-floating-action-button § Qualities

- I cannot use long press on the page because a page contains rows who can be modified/removed via the action mode that is triggered via the long press.
- It seems that my latest solution is to use the options menu[1], but I don't use it in my app.

So what should be the best pattern to allow one user to remove the current page from a swipe view ?

[1] http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#options-menu

Comment: Is a swipe up or down gesture possible?

Comment: Yeah as Alan said, maybe a different swipe might be worth looking at if you don't want to include more menu options

Comment: Vertical swipe doesn't seems possible because the pages are long and are scrollables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can :

1. Add a row for the page on the top, with the page title and creation time or whatever, then use long press to edit or delete like you do with the others rows , look at this 
   [data table](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/data-tables.html#data-tables-structure)
2. Use an "edit" floating button that take you to a page or a dialog where you can find the delete option
3. Don't follow the guidelines. Not even Google follow them all the times. A third floating button with the minus - sign would be nice and esay to understand

Comment: I'm already using the `PagerTitleStrip`to display the page title and others usefull informations (mtime, author) looks like into this `PagerTitleStrip`. So it is unclear that it can be "pressed". Actually I have placed the _edit_ and _delete_ buttons into the options menu and make the _edit_ one visible `ifRoom`. But thanks a lot for your ideas